# How to convert mongo shell query to java basicDBObject?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am having following mongo query which is executed in mongo shell.

```
db.test.update({ 
uuid: "160597270101684", 
sessionId: "160597270101684.1" 
}, { 
$setOnInsert: {
  stamps: {
    currentVisit: "1377500985", 
    lastVisit: "1377500985"
  }
},
$push:{
  visits: {
    page: "google.com",
    method: "GET"
  }
}
}, { upsert:true })
```

Because i am new to java, I am little bit confused to create the basicDBObject.

I had tried like this for sample

```
BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("uuid",1).append("session",2);
BasicDBObject upsertion = new BasicDBObject("upsert",true);
collection.update(doc,upsertion);
```

But its not working.

Any help will be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `upsert` option isn't specified with a `DBObject` but with a third argument to `DBCollection.update`

```
public WriteResult update(DBObject q, DBObject o, boolean upsert, boolean multi)
```

You'll need to form a DBObject for update by appending `$setOnInsert`, `$push`, `stamps` and `visits`.

```
BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject stamps = new BasicDBObject();
stamps.append("currentVisit", "1377500985").append("lastVisit", "1377500985");
BasicDBObject visits = new BasicDBObject();
update.append("$setOnInsert", stamps).append("$push", visits);

collection.update(doc, update, true);
```